# Regex to match punctuation except for decimal numbers

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I would like to write a regex that finds all the punctuation characters (defines as any characher that is not alphanumeric nor a space) but does not count the dots of decimal number.

So, for example, given the sentence:

> Is it x + 0.89 = y * 13.098?!?

What I want to get is

> ['+', '=', '*', '?', '!', '?']

Is there anyone who knows how to do it? It's been two days I've been trying all the possible ways to negate a regex but I cannot get it done. I hope you can help me.

Best regards,
Max

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of the following options.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/tRwTsV/1)

```
(?!\b[^\w\s]\b)[^\w\s]
```

- `(?!\b[^\w\s]\b)` Negative lookahead ensuring a non-(word or whitespace) character doesn't exist between word characters (decimal points in numbers)
- `[^\w\s]` Match any non-(word or whitespace) character

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/tRwTsV/2)

```
\B[^\w\s]|[^\w\s]\B
```

- `\B[^\w\s]` Match the following

  - `\B` Matches a location where `\b` does not match
  - `[^\w\s]` Match any non-(word or whitespace) character
- `[^\w\s]\B` Match the following

  - `[^\w\s]` Match any non-(word or whitespace) character
  - `\B` Matches a location where `\b` does not match